# How to import Session model in __init__.py ? - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

How to import `Session` model in `app/__init__.py` in Django ?

I'm trying to change the name of the default django table.
I can do this and it works perfectly by changing the direct link on site-packages.

But this is bad, because for the project the nomenclature is different so I need to do this at run time.

I tried to add in file `app/__init __.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "my_session"
```

But I get this error:

```
D:\PyEnv38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
  raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Does session model set ```abstract```  to true?

Comment: Where? Does it need to be in lib or init?

Comment: It seems to be related to the model property, I haven't worked it for a long time.

Comment: What needs to be done? Would you know how to inform?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a custom name or create a custom field in the session table, you can follow the following step.

Define a custom session backend:

```
my_project
    my_project/
        settings.py
        session_backend.py
        ...
    user/
        models.py
        ...
```

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
import user


class SessionStore(DBStore):

    @classmethod
    def get_model_class(cls):
        return user.models.MySession

    def create_model_instance(self, data):
        """
        overriding the function to save the changes to db using `session["user_id"] = user.id` .
        This will create the model instance with the custom field values. 
        When you add more field to the custom session model you have to update the function 
        to handle those fields as well.
        """
        obj = super().create_model_instance(data)
        try:
            user_id = data.get('user_id')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            user_id = None

        obj.user_id = user_id
        return obj
```

then in `setting.py` import your custom class

```py
SESSION_ENGINE = "my_project.session_backend"
```

Define the custom model in `models.py` in the app say `user`

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session


class MySession(Session):
    # you can also add custom field if required like this user column which can be the FK to the user table 
    user = models.ForeignKey('user', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    class Meta:
        app_label = "user"
        db_table = "my_session"
```

now run the following commands for migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Done :)